# Comparator not functioning as intended for PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I wrote this comparator function to be used with a priority queue. It works fine this way, it gives the words with the least frequency when I poll().

But this is frequency and I want them to behave in the opposite way. I swapped the return values -1 and +1, and that is leads to unordered and mixed results on poll().

Why does that happen, and how to fix it? Also, why is it necessary to always specify the initial size of a PriorityQueue while specifying the comparator in the constructor? Does it have any effect that I am unable to see?

```
public class StringFrequencyComparator implements Comparator<Word>
{
    public int compare(Word x, Word y)
    {
        if (x.frequency() < y.frequency())
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (x.frequency() > y.frequency())
        {
            return +1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Update: I had made a mistake. I was inserting values in the PriorityQueue and then updating their frequencies. But, I was confused because in spite of this mistake the orders were perfect for the comparator and only mixed up when I swapped the -1s and 1s values forcing me towards believing there was something wrong with the comparator. I still wonder how it was perfect.

Comment: Your comparator can be much shorter: `return x.frequency() - y.frequency();` will always work as intended.

Comment: Looks OK. What does `frequency()` return?

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek I'd appreciate it if I could know how.

Comment: Exactly the way I described.

Comment: An int value, that is private member of the Word class. The values are returned fine, but poll() is not giving me the correct order.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this comparator; there's something else wrong in your code.

Comment: Keep in mind that priority queue only sorts itself when adding or removing elements. If you put a Word in a queue and then change its frequency, you will have to sort the queue manually.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted (provided `frequency()` is idempotent). Please show us more code.

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek You are right. That was the mistake. I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Filip B. Vondrášek  The original code is safer (in case of large numbers the subtraction may overflow) and easier to understand, so it's better.

Comment: Glad you've sorted it out! :)

Comment: And also no, it could overflow only if you had words with negative frequency.

Comment: Best is probably to use `Integer.valueOf(x.frequency()).compareTo(y.frequency())`.

Comment: Best is to use `Integer.compare(x.frequency(), y.frequency())` (if you're under Java 7)